# How to get the members of an Outlook DistributionList as fast as possible?

Tags: .net, outlook, office-interop

I need to get the e-mail addresses of the members of an Outlook distribution list. This list is not in my local folder, it's a company wide list.

I have a solution, but it needs a substantial amount of time, because I iterate through all existing groups (8,400+) to find the group in question, before handling the members of this group.

Is there a better way to get the members of a distribution list, if I already know its name (no need to get all the other 8,400+ distribution lists as well)?

Here's my code:

```
outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
outlookNamespace = _outlookApp.GetNamespace("mapi")

Dim addrLists As Outlook.AddressLists =
    outlookApp.Session.AddressLists
Dim root As Outlook.AddressList =
    addrLists.OfType(Of Outlook.AddressList) _
             .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "All Groups")
Dim entry As Outlook.AddressEntry =
    root.AddressEntries.Cast(Of Outlook.AddressEntry) _
                       .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "<Enter Group Name Here>")
```

`entry.Members` contains all the members of this list.

---

I tried to use the function `GetAddressEntryFromID` but I only get an error "Unfortunately a problem occured. You can try again." (translated from german).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot simpler than that:

```
set allGroups = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Groups")
set addressEntry = allGroups.AddressEntries.Item("<Enter Group Name Here>")
for each m in addressEntry.Members
  MsgBox m.Name
next
```

Comment: Does an address list "all groups" always exist, in any language version of Outlook? Otherwise my solution doesn't depend on knowing the language specific name of the "all groups" list to work?

Comment: Also, if you use `allGroups.AddressEntries.Item` with a list name, that not exists, then it delivers another `AddressEntry` with a name similar to the one you were looking for. I tried to get the non existing list "Horst" and got the list "HOS" instead.
Using my solution I can use `rec.Resolved` to check, if my recipient really exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.

```
Dim rec As Outlook.Recipient =
    outlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("<Enter Group Name Here>")
rec.Resolve
```

`rec.AddressEntry.Members` contains all the members of the list.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use CreateRecipient (whcih ca raise ambiguous name errors) - you already have the AddressEntry object.

Comment: Your solution works but does depend on a list called "All Groups" to exist. Is that always the case, in any language version of Outlook?

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes the `Resolve` didn't work even though the given group name does exist, so I switched to the other way again and check whether the found group name equals the given group name to know whether the given group really exists.

Comment: Yes, "All Groups" name is localized, but unfortunately there is no special tag that identifies it as such. The only list that does is "All rooms".